# unable to declare string globally from json

Tags: android, json, string

I am trying to get a value from remote json and convert it into a globally defined string so that I can use it for sharing purpose. I have managed to use that string to set a textview but when I further try to use the same string in onCreateOptionsMenu, it gives me null value. Even I cant get the string from that textview declared in LoadService to use it in OncreateOption.

share_string is globally defined string and its value is declared in LoadService and I want to use it in OnCreateOptionMnu. Any help will be most welcomed.

```
private class LoadService extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void> {

    private final HttpClient Client = new DefaultHttpClient();
    private String Content;
    private String Error = null;
    private final String TAG = null;
    private ProgressDialog Dialog = new ProgressDialog(Advertisment_Page.this);


    protected void onPreExecute() {
        // NOTE: You can call UI Element here.

        // UI Element
        Dialog.setMessage("Loading service..");
        Dialog.show();
    }

    // Call after onPreExecute method
    public Void doInBackground(String... urls) {
        try {

            // NOTE: Don't call UI Element here.

            HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet(urls[0]);
            ResponseHandler<String> responseHandler = new BasicResponseHandler();
            Content = Client.execute(httpget, responseHandler);

        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            Error = e.getMessage();
            cancel(true);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Error = e.getMessage();
            cancel(true);
        }

        return null;
    }

    public void onPostExecute(Void unused) {
        // NOTE: You can call UI Element here.

        // Close progress dialog
        Dialog.dismiss();
        Log.e(TAG, "------------------------------------- Output: "
                + Content);
        try {

            // Load json data and display
            JSONObject json = new JSONObject(Content);

            title_tv.setText(json.getString("title"));

            share_string=(json.getString("rupees"));
            rupees_tv.setText(share_string);

            relativeLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);




        } catch (JSONException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_share, menu);
    mShareActionProvider = (ShareActionProvider) menu.findItem(R.id.share).getActionProvider();

    /** Setting a share intent */
    mShareActionProvider.setShareIntent(getDefaultShareIntent());

    return true;
}

private Intent getDefaultShareIntent(){
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    intent.setType("text/plain");
    intent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT,share_string);
    intent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, share_string);
    return intent;
}


}
```

Comment: where you call your asynctask, it may happen beacuse oncreateoptionmenu called before completion of asynctask hence your shared string contain null value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AsyncTask is asynchronous call so `onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)` called before `onPostExecute(Void unused)` call.

So you need to call onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) manually by calling
`invalidateOptionsMenu()`  at the end of `onPostExecute(Void unused)` method.